# How does a model that has both convolutional layers and recurrent layers behave?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Suppose I have the following model in keras:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="valid",
                        input_shape=[None, 1]),
     keras.layers.GRU(20, return_sequences=True),
     keras.layers.GRU(20, return_sequences=True),
     keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1))
])
```

It will be fed a univariate time series data and it will predict the next value in the time series data.

It has a convolutional layer that is meant to downsample the inputs, and that is followed by 2 GRU units that will process each time step. Suppose this is how the inputs `X` and the outputs `Y` look like, in terms of indices. There are 51 samples in this dataset. At each index `X`, the prediction `Y` is one step ahead in the data set.

```
X: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 ... 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
Y: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 ... 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

After I apply the convolutional layer, the inputs `X` will change and that means we will also have to change the outputs `Y`. The convolutional layer will take 4 samples from the dataset and transform it in 1 scalar that will represent the 4 samples. Since we have 20 filters, this will be done 20 times for each combination of 4 samples in the dataset, with a stride of 2. So this is how the convolutional layer will be applied on the inputs dataset:

```
              |-----2-----|     |-----5---...------|     |-----23----|
        |-----1-----|     |-----4-----|   ...      |-----22----|
  |-----0----|      |-----3-----|     |---...|-----21----|
X: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 ... 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
Y: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 ... 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

After the convolutional layer is applied, the inputs `X` and the modified outputs `Y` will look like this:

```
X:     0/3   2/5   4/7   6/9   8/11  10/13 ... 42/45  44/47  46/49
Y:      4     6     8    10     12     14       46     48     50
```

Where, for example, `0/3` in `X` means a representation of the first 4 samples in the original data and each instance in the new `X` is actually a 20D vector since we used 20 filters in the convolutional layer. We also had to change the output data, so that the algorithm can't look into the future. It will still predict the value of the time series one step ahead, but we had to change `Y` such that now each sample is one step ahead of the new `X`.

Suppose I compile and train this model. This is what I am confused about: Suppose I want to use this in the real world. I get 1 sample from the real world. How will this one sample be processed through the model? Don't I need 4 samples in order for the convolutional layer to be properly applied? If I now have just this one new instance, not 4, how can the model predict the next value? What will happen? I am really confused about how this will work...

Comment: If you introduce convolution layer don't you think yo are introducing additional trainable parameter ?

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly in that you have only 1 sequence with 51 time steps in your initial dataset? Does the above model actually work with your data?

Comment: @Akash_Kumar Yes, I introduce additional trainable parameters. I know. What about it?

Comment: @runDOSrun Not necessarly just 1 sequence, there could be more sequences. It is a slightly modified example from "Hands-on Machine Learning" by Aurelion Geron. In the book the algorithm didn't predict just 1 step ahead, but actually 10 steps ahead. So if we are at time t, the algorithm from the book would predict the values at times t+1, t+2, ..., t+10. The author used 10000 sequences of length 51, so it's not just one sequence. Still, the question stands. If I get 1 sample from the real world, how does the algorithm make a prediction? How does that 1 sample go through the convolutional layer?

Comment: The problem is that your use of "samples" is ambivalent: I think by "1 sample" you don't mean "1 sequence of length 51" but rather "1 sequence of length 1", right? That's the problem. A 2D CNN isn't really trained to do that. It's trained for sequences of 51 elements. You can certainly do it but would have to either a) get rid of the CNN and run your RNN in `stateful` mode  or b) train on sequence lengths of 4 (not 51).

Comment: [continued] However, you actually have a 1D CNN! The CNN is operating *per timestep*. Each entry in Y represents *one timestep*, same has to be true for X: If X is just a single number, there is nothing to convolve! If it's an array, we have a sequene of arrays. You can see this if you inspect your shapes. Therefore the CNN isn't an issue and can predict given a single timestep.

Comment: @runDOSrun Yes, by "1 sample"  I mean that we get a sequence of length 1 from the real world. How would that go through the convolutional layer, and then through the rest of the model? Because I have a 1D convolutional layer in the model as the first layer, isn't the model now expecting 4 values (a sequence of length 4) before it can make a prediction, since the kernel size of the convolutional layer is 4? If I feed the network a sequence of length 1 from the real world, will I get a prediction? Whatever the answer is, how does it work? How can it go through the model? Or how does it behave?

Comment: What is the size of your input for each timestep? Is it a single number or an array? If it's an array, the convolution is done on the **features** and not the **timesteps**. If it's literally a single number, your design doesn't make much sense since you would destroy the sequence with the CNNs and the RNNs wouldn't have anything to work with (hence my unanswered question if you've actually implemented this!). If it's a single number, read my previous 2 comments again to understand.